# How to send requests while receiving responses in IB API?

Tags: python, api, stream

I don't quite understand how to go about using IB API Wrapper and Client streams. I understand that I am sending out requests to the IB server through the Client stream and am receiving the response through the Wrapper stream, but I would like to be able to implement a menu for the user such as "Press 'p' for open positions, etc." followed by a display of the server response and a prompt for another action.

```
from ibapi import wrapper
from ibapi.client import EClient
from ibapi.utils import iswrapper

# types
from ibapi.common import *
from ibapi.contract import *


class TestClient(EClient):
    def __init__(self, wrapper):
        EClient.__init__(self, wrapper)


class TestWrapper(wrapper.EWrapper):
    def __init__(self):
        wrapper.EWrapper.__init__(self)


class TestApp(TestWrapper, TestClient):
    def __init__(self):
        TestWrapper.__init__(self)
        TestClient.__init__(self, wrapper=self)

    def position(self, account: str, contract: Contract, position: float,
                 avgCost: float):
        """This event returns real-time positions for all accounts in
        response to the reqPositions() method."""

        super().position(account, contract, position, avgCost)
        print("Position.", account, "Symbol:", contract.symbol, "SecType:",
              contract.secType, "Currency:", contract.currency,
              "Position:", position, "Avg cost:", avgCost)


def main():
    app = TestApp()
    usr_in = ''

    app.connect("127.0.0.1", 7497, clientId=0)
    print("serverVersion:%s connectionTime:%s" % (app.serverVersion(),
                                              app.twsConnectionTime()))

    while(usr_in != 'exit'):
         usr_in = input('What to do next?')
         if usr_in == 'p':
             app.reqPositions()

    app.run()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

What ends up happening now is that the program asks for input, but does not display the server response until I exit the loop, after which it does display the response. I know I can include some logic within the position() function, but this is very limiting and there must be a better way to interact with the two streams. Also, a pointer to any further readings on the topic of streams like the ones used in IB API will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out! All needs to be done is to start two threads. One will be be handling the run() function of EClient, the other will be running the loop function of the app. Here is what the code would look like:

```
from ibapi import wrapper
from ibapi.client import EClient
from ibapi.contract import *

import threading
import time


class TestApp(wrapper.EWrapper, EClient):
    def __init__(self):
        wrapper.EWrapper.__init__(self)
        EClient.__init__(self, wrapper=self)

        self.connect("127.0.0.1", 7497, clientId=0)
        print(f"serverVersion:{self.serverVersion()}
              connectionTime:{self.twsConnectionTime()}")

    def position(self, account: str, contract: Contract, position: float,
                 avgCost: float):
        """This event returns real-time positions for all accounts in
        response to the reqPositions() method."""

        super().position(account, contract, position, avgCost)
        print("Position.", account, "Symbol:", contract.symbol, "SecType:",
              contract.secType, "Currency:", contract.currency,
              "Position:", position, "Avg cost:", avgCost)

    def loop(self):
        while True:
            self.reqPositions()
            time.sleep(15)


def main():
    app = TestApp()

    reader_thread = threading.Thread(target=app.run)
    loop_thread = threading.Thread(target=app.loop)

    reader_thread.start()
    loop_thread.start()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```